# show it is a random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let X and Y be random variables and let A be an event. Show that
the function
$$Z(\omega)=\begin{cases}X(\omega) \quad \text{if} \; \omega \in A\\
Y(\omega) \quad \text{if} \; \omega \in A^c
\end{cases}$$
is a random variable.
I considered the case in which $Z(\omega)=I_A(\omega)$, where
$$I_{A}(\omega)=\begin{cases}1 \quad \text{if} \; \omega \in A\\
0 \quad \text{if} \; \omega \in A^c
\end{cases}$$
since the indicator is a measurable function.

Is my intuition correct?

Many thanks

Comment: So the whole question is how you know the piecwise function is measurable?

Comment: Hint: try to write $Z$ as a polynomial in $X$, $Y$ and $I_A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is measurable, then the indicator function $1_A$ is measurable.

Sums and products of measurable functions are measurable, hence $Z = X \cdot 1_A + Y \cdot 1_{A^c}$ is measurable.